# Subclassing NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking, nsurlsession

**TL;DR** Is there any common pattern of using `NSURLSession` in *whole* application by simply creating a new client class just the way you subclass `AFHTTPSessionManager`?

---

I like to use [`AFNetworking`](http://afnetworking.com) for many reasons and if I see no contraindications I use it with a pleasure but sometimes I've got a relatively simple task to achieve and `AFNetworking` seems to be an overkill or I simply need to avoid third party dependencies.

With that in my mind I realise that guys from Apple provided us with a cool thing called `NSURLSession` and it sounds like a perfect soultion for many cases but when I star reading about using it in projects, well I want to get back to `AFNetworking` let me explain why...

When you plan to create a custom class for your networking task using `AFNetworking` you simply create a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` (of course if you're dealing with HTTP) and simply return singleton and so on... (If you don't know the rest of the story, check [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial))
Simple, right?
But what if I want to subclass `NSURLSession` in the same way? Well, I'm still searching the Internet for a solution but so far no luck here... Every tutorial, every article, every post state that you instantiate `NSURLSession` in your view controller and if needed you use it, period. But what happend in case I want to use this client throughout my whole application?

Comment: Why do you need a subclass? What are you trying to achieve by subclassing?

Comment: @jtbandes I want to create a class which I'll be able to use everywhere in my app to create a calls to external API. I don't want to put boilerplate `NSURL..` code everywhere insted I'd like to call more meningful methods like `fetchAllUsers:` or so.

Answer (score 2):

For the use case you describe, it would be much simpler to make a singleton that has an `NSURLSession` as a property than to subclass it. See **[Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/1445366)**

> Every tutorial, every article, every post state that you instantiate `NSURLSession` in your view controller and if needed you use it, period.

A view controller should typically not have any `NSURL…` classes in it, because a view controller should be told what to display, it shouldn't be asking. It's way outside the realm of what a view controller should do.

Comment: So what you're trying to tell me is to drop the idea of inheritance here and create a regular class which will be a singleton. That makes sens!